# How can i decode Html tags on Xamarin Forms

Tags: html, xamarin, decode

I'm getting list of data from API. Those are
*Id
*Description
*MinPhotoPath
*MaxPhotoPath

**I want to get Description  Like this**

**Lorem ipsum** dolor sit amet, <s>consectetur adipiscing elit</s>, *sed do eiusmod* tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

but i get infront of Lorem ipsum  p and strong which is inside html tags and  i'm getting infront of consectetur s  inside html tags, something like that...

I tried to use WebUtility.HtmlDecode but its only decode the at the end of the text "\r\n".
I'm waiting for your help.Thanks.

Comment: are you asking how to get the plain text without any markup?

Comment: i want to use tags functions, for example instead of see the strong tag , i want to see the bold text .

Comment: try using AngleSharp

Comment: Thaks for your suggestion.I will try this. There are any other solution except AngleSharp ?

Comment: May I ask why do you want to strip the tags out? If your only purpose is to display in a label, you could write renderers or may be [this HtmlLabelPlugin can help](https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin)

Comment: shan thank u very much it works  :)